# Azure DevOps IIS Deployment failing

Tags: iis, azure-devops, azure-virtual-machine, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a release pipeline to deploy my ASP.NET MVC web app to Azure VM. I have configured the release pipeline and everything was working fine.

But all of a sudden, it started throwing the error shown here. I am using IIS Web App deployment tool for this in Azure DevOps:

[image]

Comment: From the picture, seems we can find [the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxZd4.png), pls copy all the command, and share with us. Let me double confirm it. By the way, please share your task screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's been reported as an issue related to a new task versions for WebAppDeployment tasks.  See here, you might find a workaround that will work for you:  https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/17634